# Data binding not working in AngularJS with input tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Below is my angularjs code,
When I try to enter any text in the textbox, it doesn't appear in the binding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('cont', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <input type="text" ng-bind="user"></input>
    <p>{{user}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use [`ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive for 2-way binding. [`ng-bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) is just one-way which updates the bound element with data (model value) when a digest cycle happens. Without ng-model when you update the textbox there wont be any digest cycle. Angular has [directive definition for types like `input`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d40749caabfbdaf867973bb6e8de75f64902f13a/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1529) and other form controls which requires optional `ng-model` directive. And these element directives registers events like `change/input` etc only if it [gets the optional ng-model controller](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d40749caabfbdaf867973bb6e8de75f64902f13a/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1536) on the target element. And when you have them it uses ng-model controller to set the view-value, model-value and triggers the digest cycle when [that event occurs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d40749caabfbdaf867973bb6e8de75f64902f13a/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1037). Of course  with the new angular versions there is an [`ng-model-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) which you can set at the element level or at a global level to specify when do you want the model value update (and form validation) to happen.

So do:-

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user" name="user"></input>
<p>{{user}}</p>
```

Though not an issue in your case, you are missing the usage of `ng-controller="cont"`. Without it all properties will be attached to the rootScope in your case. So may be:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="cont">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user" name="user"></input>
    <p>{{user}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```